# Front tracking approximations and existence of solutions to conservation law PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, conservation-laws

This question is about page 38-42 of [these notes](http://php.math.unifi.it/users/cimeCourses/2009/01/200912-Notes.pdf) on censervation laws, more precisely PDEs of the form $u_t + [f(u)]_x =0.$ In this section of the note, the author provides a proof of the existence of an entropic solution to the differential equation with initial condition $u_0$, where the **total variation** of $u_0$ is sufficiently small. The method of proof is to consider approximation of $u_0$ by piecewise linear functions. Here is another reference for this method of proof: [Ronald JDiPerna. Global existence of solutions to nonlinear hyperbolic systems of conservation laws.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039676901029)

Page 38-42 is about how to deal with the issue that we may get infinitely many wavefronts (discontinuities) within finite time. A simplified front-tracking process is given. given three states $u_l,u_m,u_r$ (left, middle, right) related by $u_m = \Psi_j(\sigma) u_l, u_r =\Psi_{j'}(\sigma') u_m,$ one can define the auxiliary right state (**bottom of page 39**)
$$
\tilde u_r = \Psi_j(\sigma) \circ \Psi_{j'}(\sigma') (u_l), \text{for }j> j'
$$

The semigroup $\Psi$ describes how different states $u$ are related to each other. A definition of $\Psi$ can be found on page 20 of the notes. The larger the value of $j,$ the faster the characteristic speed of the wavefront.

So we kind of **"re-order"** the way we apply $\Psi$ according to which of $j,j'$ is **bigger**.  Then we introduce a nonphysical wave front to connect $\tilde u_r$ and $u_r$ together.

Now I am having difficulties understanding the following things:
**Why do we need to reorder $\Psi$ in the definition of $\tilde u?$** Apparently this is to ensure that the solution is piecewise constant (so no rarefaction waves will appear). But why does this ensure that we do not have a rarefaction wave?

At the end of page 39, the notes say that this is due to euqation $(4.25)$ on page 37:

> Because of (4.25), the piecewise constant function $\tilde v$ contains exactly two wave-fronts...

but I am unable to see why $(4.25)$ is useful here. Why and how are we utilizing $(4.25)?$

I really wish to include more detail in this question, but if I quote an equation, I need to include the definition of all the terms/symbols, and there are simply too many of them to be included here. Please feel free to ignore the details which I have not included. **The most important thing is: why this construction works?** An explanation to just this question would be extremely helpful.